# Deselecting a column without deletion in Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a numpy array in this form:

```
n = [[[5 0 2]
  [8 9 7]
  [2 2 2]
  [5 9 5]   <-- target value
  [4 1 5]]
 [[5 3 9]
  [4 2 7]
  [7 0 7]
  [4 9 6]   <-- target value
  [3 8 5]]]
```

I want to get all the values except the 3rd row from each individual array. ie. the results should be in this way:

```
 [[[5 0 2]
  [8 9 7]
  [2 2 2]
  [4 1 5]]

 [[5 3 9]
  [4 2 7]
  [7 0 7]
  [3 8 5]]]
```

I tried using indexing, but I cannot achieve it. I have a large numpy array where this operation needs to be done. Is there any efficient method to do it, other than making a copy of it and removing it using delete method. **Also, I don't want to utilize much space by creating a copy, I just want to use indexing to ignore the particular column for a while.**

Comment: While it's easy to do with `advanced` indexing, the result will be a copy, not a `view`.  The selection pattern is not regular enough for a view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this and it worked:

```
You can try using this method:
t = np.array([[[5, 0, 2],
        [8, 9, 7],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [5, 9, 5],
        [4, 1, 5]],

       [[5, 3, 9],
        [4, 2, 7],
        [7, 0, 7],
        [4, 9, 6],
        [3, 8, 5]]])
t[:,[0,1,2,4]]
```

Comment: This creates a copy of your array in the form of the temporary array `t[:, [0, 1, 2, 4]]`. This goes against the requirements in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of selected elements, popping the target one:

```
import numpy as np

n = np.array([[[5,0,2],
               [8,9,7],
               [2,2,2],
               [5,9,5],   
               [4,1,5]],
              [[5,3,9],
               [4,2,7],
               [7,0,7],
               [4,9,6], 
               [3,8,5]]])

target_element = 3

s = list(range(len(n[0])))
s.pop(target_element)
print(n[:,s])
```

or

```
s = list(range(len(n[0])))
print(n[:,s[:target_element] + s[target_element+1:]])
```